# How to get Validation script to work with Mootools form

Tags: ajax, forms, validation, mootools

I hope you can help,

I am relatively new to mootools

I have been using http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/fvalidator/ to validate some webforms and I wanted to try and use it with an Ajax form. It is an oldish website using Mootools 1.2.5.

http://jsfiddle.net/jessicajet/gTqV8/ is the form I am trying to use it with. (The fValidator script is not added here)

This is what I am using to submit the form

```
formtostop.addEvent("submit", function(e) {
    e.stop();
    new Request({
        url: this.get("action"),
        method: "post",
        data: this,
        onRequest: function() {
            document.id("result").set("html", "sending...");
        },
        onComplete: function() {
            document.id("result").set({html: '<div class="response"><p>Thank you for completing our contact form, we will get back to you as soon as possible</p></div>', style: 'background:red'});
        }
    }).send();
});
```

When I hit submit the validation and the ajax form fires, which is to be expected.

Can I get the submit button to look for the validation script before the e.stop(); new Request({ or am I trying to do something not possible?

I will appreciate any advice that can be offered.

Comment: http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/fvalidator/js/fValidator-full.js

Answer (score 1):

http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/fvalidator/js/fValidator-full.js, take a look at the _onSubmit function. You should extend this class (http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class) and modify the _onSubmit function to do a request if the isValid statement is true.